# How to replace execfile() with exec() in Pydev on Ctrl+Alt+Enter key binding?

Tags: python-3.x, pydev

There's a problem in Pydev 2.5 and Python 3.2 with trying to load the module contents "into" the interactive console: when you hit Ctrl+Alt+Enter, Pydev fires execfile(filename) instead of exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'), globals, locals) - the latter being execfile()'s replacement in Python 3+...

So, how to change this behaviour?

ETA: to be a bit more concrete, things go like this: I create a new PyDev Module, say 'test.py', write some simple function def f(n): print(n), hit Ctrl+Alt+Enter, then I select "Console for currently active editor" and Python 3.2 interpreter, interactive console wakes up, and then I get this:

```
>>> import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
PyDev console: using default backend (IPython not available).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\3.2\python.exe 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:15:24) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

>>> execfile('C:\\testy.py')
>>> f(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

As you can see, it still uses execfile() instead of exec(), that replaced it in Python 3+...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

The actual problem is that the execfile is not getting the proper globals in the PyDev redefinition. So, if the execfile did execfile('my_file', globals()), it would work... I'll change the implementation of PyDev so that if the globals is not passed, it'll do:

```
if glob is None:
    import sys
    glob = sys._getframe().f_back.f_globals
```

(you can fix that in your local install at **plugins/org.python.pydev_XXX/PySrc/_pydev_execfile.py** and it should work -- please let me know if it doesn't).

---

INITIAL ANSWER:

That's not possible, but PyDev does redefine execfile when you're in its console on Python 3, so, it should still work... is that not working for you for some reason?

Also, the replacement: exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'), globals, locals) is broken for some situations in Python 3.

The actual redefinition (which should work in all situations and is available in PyDev) is:

```
#We must redefine it in Py3k if it's not already there
def execfile(file, glob=None, loc=None):
    if glob is None:
        glob = globals()
    if loc is None:
        loc = glob
    stream = open(file, 'rb')
    try:
        encoding = None
        #Get encoding!
        for _i in range(2):
            line = stream.readline() #Should not raise an exception even if there are no more contents
            #Must be a comment line
            if line.strip().startswith(b'#'):
                #Don't import re if there's no chance that there's an encoding in the line
                if b'coding' in line:
                    import re
                    p = re.search(br"coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)", line)
                    if p:
                        try:
                            encoding = p.group(1).decode('ascii')
                            break
                        except:
                            encoding = None
    finally:
        stream.close()

    if encoding:
        stream = open(file, encoding=encoding)
    else:
        stream = open(file)
    try:
        contents = stream.read()
    finally:
        stream.close()

    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) #execute the script
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if I was being understood so I added the specific steps that lead to the problem, and now I'm trying to figure out how should I use this redefinition you posted to fix this annoying little bug (if indeed it is a bug)...

Comment: Ok, just saw the error there... it doesn't get the correct globals(). Will fix answer to reflect that.

Comment: It works! :) 
There's only a minor mistake there in the path - it should be:
plugins\org.python.pydev_XXX\PySrc\_pydev_execfile.py
(last backslash was missing)

Comment: Fixed that... note: please mark the answer as 'correct' if it worked for you :)